# How to use transitions with UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've been looking through some very helpful examples on how implement custom transitions between segues (e.g [this one](http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/)).

But I just can't figure out how to do this with `UISplitViewController`.

Can I get any hint/tips?

I know that in the `MasterViewController` you can `prepareForSegue` when showing a new `DetailedViewController`. But setting the `transitioningDelegate` on the `destinationViewController` does not seem to work at all.

I also tried to set the `MasterViewController`as the `NavigationViewControllerDelegate` and return the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, but that didn't work either (as expected, but I wanted to try).

Comment: Did you see this delegate method: 
- splitViewController:showDetailViewController:sender:

Comment: I'm curious to know if you managed to customise the transition with UISplitViewController. In my case I'm more interested in animating (and also having interactive transitions) while opening/closing the primary view controller while it's configured as overlay mode. Can't find any documentation/example about that.